# Add UDID's to developer account after reaches 100 count

Tags: app-store-connect, udid, renewal

Recently I renewal my developer account. But unfortunately i didn't delete UDID's from the list. Now it reaches 100. I have 9 months time to again renewal my account. SO how can i add new UDID's ? Is there any chance again to renewal my account for adding/ Managing devices.Please provide me suggestion.

Comment: After renewal Apple Dev Portal suggested you remove unnecessary device UDIDs from list. What have you done when saw this suggestion?

Comment: We transferred all the UDID's to next step.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to remove old UDIDs before next license renewal.

So I suggest you to buy second developer license and use it for you needs.